# Why is the set R = $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} | |x| < |y| \bigvee x=y) \}$ a partial order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

For a set to be a total order it must have 4 properties:

1. Reflexive
2. Antisymmetry
3. Transitive
4. $\forall x \in A\forall y \in A((x,y) \in R \bigvee (y,x) \in R)$, where A is a set and R is a relation on that set.

I have checked the first three and found that R is a partial order on $\mathbb{R}$; when I check this fourth property I get that:

$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} [|x| < |y| \bigvee |y| < |x| \bigvee x=y]
$$
I cannot find a counter example to this last statement. It seems that any pair of real numbers (x,y) will satisfy one of the three properties of the previous statement - but that would make this a total order, not a partial order.

Comment: Incidentally, a total order _is_ a partial order--it's just a very special kind of partial order.

Comment: @TonyK That doesn't work - the ordering is on $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$. (So the order relation $R$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Comment: Would the pairs (-1,1) and (1,-1) suffice?

Comment: It seems there's some confusion over the domain of the ordering - the relation you've described is a partial order on $\mathbb{R}$, **not** $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So, the counter example would be: x=1 and y=-1, two real numbers. While the ordered pairs (1,-1) and (-1,1) are not in R, thus R is a partial order but not a total order.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: the absolute value function isn't injective . . .

Comment: The pairs (1, -1) and (-1,1) would be a counter example then, since they have the same absolute value - but are not equal. Correct?

Comment: Sort of - it's more correct to say that $x=1, y=-1$ is a counterexample. What you've written makes it sound like you want to set $x=(1, -1)$, $y=(-1, 1)$ to get a counterexample; but then $x$ and $y$ aren't reals, so the relation doesn't even apply to them.

Comment: Ah yes, since the fourth relation is in reference to two individual real numbers - not ordered pairs of real numbers.